# Compare list in C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I create two lists like,

```
            var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "abc"));
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2", "def"));
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("3", "ghi"));


            var list2 = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("1", "abc"));
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("2", "def"));
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("3", "ghi"));
            list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("4", "jkl"));

           var unmatchedlist= new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

how to compare the two lists.now I need **list.Add(new KeyValuePair("4", "jkl"));** (because it is not in firstlist but its avail in secondlist )in unmatchedlist?

Comment: It might help if you explained why you want to do this. As it stands now, `list = list2;` would be a solution (but I assume that's not what you want). Also, in your comparison, do you consider two lists equal if they have the same elements, but in a different order?

Answer (score 2):

one way to do this :

```
list1 = list1.Union(list2);
```

OR :

```
list1.AddRange(list1.Except(list2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the differences between list2 and list:

```
var unmatched = list2.Except(list);
```

Then just add the items into list that appear in unmatched.

Comment: Good idea, but it should be other way around I think :)

Comment: It looks as thought after list2 is declared that more items are being added to the earlier list variable. not sure if that's correct or not. But from this the OP can switch things around where needed.

Comment: It doesn't matter how it looks - OP clearly wants to do `list.Add` so what is missing in `list` is of interest :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this way

```
//This will be empty
var difference1 = list1.Except(list2);
```

Or the other way arround

```
//This will contain item 4
var difference2 = list2.Except(list1);
```